# PHP result row as an object not set

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this PHP code in which I try to edit a row in the database

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `event` where `EId`='".$_GET['EId']."'";
$res=$conn->query($sql);
$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($numrows>0)
{
  $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($res);
} 

if ($_REQUEST["mode"]=="save")
{
  if ($_FILES['image']['name']!="")
  {
    del_img("event/",$obj->Picture);
    $Picture=post_img($_FILES['image']['name'], $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"event");
  }
  else
    $Picture = $obj->Picture;

  $sqlu="update event set Picture='".$Picture."' where EId='".$_POST['EId']."'";

  $conn->query($sqlu);
  header("refresh:1; url=event_view.php");
  die();

}

function post_img($fileName,$tempFile,$targetFolder)
{ 
  if ($fileName!="")
  {
    if(!(is_dir($targetFolder)))
      mkdir($targetFolder);
    $counter=0;
    $NewFileName=$fileName;
    if(file_exists($targetFolder."/".$NewFileName))
    {
      do
      { 
        $counter=$counter+1;
        $NewFileName=$counter."".$fileName;
      }
      while(file_exists($targetFolder."/".$NewFileName));
    }
    $NewFileName=str_replace(",","-",$NewFileName);
    $NewFileName=str_replace(" ","_",$NewFileName); 
    copy($tempFile, $targetFolder."/".$NewFileName);  
    return $NewFileName;
  }
}

function del_img($targetfolder,$filname)
{
  if (file_exists($targetfolder.$filname))
  {
    unlink($targetfolder.$filname);
  }
}
```

When this is executed without uploading a new image it removes the present image and saves the row without any image. When uploading a new image it does not delete the current image.

I checked with isset and it tells me that the variable $obj->Picture is not set. I used this code in an older version of PHP and it still works but I can't seem to get it to work in the current one. 
I am quite sure that the problem lies with $obj but I can't seem figure out what it is.

The HTML is just a form with file upload input and I have already set up a connection to the database with $conn being a new mysqli. The reason I am taking the entire row is because I am editing other stuff too

It feels like I am committing a fundamental mistake? What am I missing?

Comment: All the code in the `if ($_REQUEST["mode"]=="save")` block should be inside the `if ($numrows>0)` block since it depends on `$obj` being set, and `$obj` is only set in that if block.

Comment: But that would break the functionality. How would it even get to the ($_REQUEST["mode"]=="save") part? I used the exact same code in an older version of PHP and it works fine

Comment: Then you need to restructure your code so that it doesn't rely on `$obj` being set unless you are updating an existing row.

Comment: But it works for an older version. Why would it get more difficult with a newer version?

Comment: This is very dangerous code. Not only are you dropping user-supplied data directly into your database queries, you're also putting it into your filesystem.

Comment: @miken32 This is a page in the backend so only the web admin is going to be using this so no security is needed apart from some basic things

Comment: Yeah, some basic things like making sure they can't overwrite sensitive files or corrupt every record in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet there is some Problem with the num_rows_function.

Try to structure the code differently or at least make sure you have obj defined and initialised when the part of your code where the object is required is reached.

Do something like this for xample:

```
   if ($_REQUEST["mode"]=="save"  && isset($obj))
   {
    if (($_FILES['image']['name']!=""))
   {
    del_img("event/",$obj->Picture);
    $Picture=post_img($_FILES['image']['name'], $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"event");
    }
   else
   $Picture = $obj->Picture;

   $sqlu="update event set Picture='".$Picture."' where EId='".$_POST['EId']."'";
  (...)
```

Comment: In development I would recommend to take a look at the output of numrows - i guess that will help to indicate why it sometimes did not work :)

Comment: Well the thing is I know it is not set. So this would never run. I want to know why it works in a older version but fails to work in this version. Another thing that I tried was removing the if($numrows>0) condition and leaving the $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($res) without the if statement. Now the var is set yet I have the same problem

Comment: if you do print_r($numrows);  - what is the given output? Does $conn->query(); deliver a proper mysqli-query-result? Don't know how old the script is, but during the process of refactoring the old mysql-functions to the mysqli-ones sometimes errors occured due to the fact that some mysqli-functions had a different set of parameters they expected than the mysql-functions before, and even their output sometimes differed. that was quite a source of untypical errors. I'm not that deep in php-developement actually today, but that would be a typical situation that occured in the past.

Comment: print_r($numrows); is one

Comment: And I am pretty sure $conn->query(); delivers a proper query as I have used it in other places where it works

Comment: ok I see - so please print_r($obj); and make sure the array has a key $obj['Picture']; (of course it's case sensitive here)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's how I would fix this up. Your whole logic was messed up; now we have only the two conditions we need: is a valid EId sent, and is a file attached?

Database API is updated to something a tiny bit more modern, queries are prepared and parameterized for security, and we are properly sanitizing user input before using it to name files.

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "password");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Picture FROM event WHERE EId = ?");
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST["EId"]]);
if ($obj = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    if (!empty($_FILES["image"])) {
        del_img("event/", $obj->Picture);
        $Picture = post_img($_FILES['image'], "event");
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE event SET Picture = ? WHERE EId = ?");
        $result = $stmt->execute([$Picture, $_POST["EId"]]);
    }
    header("Location: event_view.php");
    die();
}

function post_img($file, $targetFolder)
{
    if (!(is_dir($targetFolder))) {
        mkdir($targetFolder);
    }
    $fileName = $file["name"];
    $tempFile = $file["tmp_name"];

    $NewFileName = str_replace([",", " "], ["-", "_"], basename($fileName));

    $counter = 0;
    while(file_exists($targetFolder . "/" . $NewFileName)) { 
        $counter += 1;
        $NewFileName = $counter . $fileName;
    }
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFolder . "/" . $NewFileName);  
    return $NewFileName;
}

function del_img($targetfolder,$filname)
{
    if (file_exists($targetfolder . $filname)) {
        unlink($targetfolder.$filname);
    }
}
```